# Gerador automático de nomes

Tags: c#

É o seginte eu percisava de quando alguem clicar num botão numa text box aparecesse um nome ao calhas por exemplo

Tenho uma lista: Neuro, Food, Capitalism

quando eu clicasse no botão, na textbox aparecia

Neuro Capitalism

ou

capitalism food

ou

Neuro Food

**Update**
Tive a pesquisar mais um pouco e consegui fazer isto

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var words = new[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
    var wordss = new[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
    var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
    var wordsInRandomOrders = wordss.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = word;
    }
    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrders)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + wordss;
    }
}
```

o problema é que nesta parte

```
foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrders)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + wordss;
}
```

em vez de por uma das palavras em `var wordss`

Ele está a por isto

pineappleSystem.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]

Oque tenho de fazer.

**Update 2**
Eu estive a altera o código e agora está assim

```
        var words = new[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
        var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = word;
    }

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + word;
    }
}
```

Já apareçe não aparece pineappleSystem.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]

mas agora apareçe

guavamangobananapineappleappleguavapapaya

Como altero o forever para fazer uma vez apenas.

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida? Este site não é um fórum e muito menos um classificado para encontrar programadores. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].

Comment: @LuizVieira a minha duvida é como fazer aquilo que demonstrei em cima eu tento mas não consigo encontrar em sitio nenhum como se faz

Comment: "Como fazer" é muito amplo. Tem inúmeras possibilidades. Qual é a que você tentou? Vc diz que "tenta mas não consegue". Que tal colocar o trecho de código que você já tentou e explicar onde você acredita que está tendo dificuldade? Fica mais fácil de alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @LuizVieira eu não encontrei como fazer o que eu quero

Comment: É que dificilmente você vai encontrar um tutorial ou material que descreva *exatamente* o que você quer, né? Você estudou as partes do seu problema? Vc já sabe como representar os nomes dentro do seu programa? Vc já sabe como sortear um número aleatório? Enfim, vc ao menos entende a lógica por trás da solução do seu problema? Não basta procurar pela solução mágica, vc precisa refletir um pouco sobre o problema. E não leve a mal nada deste comentário, ok? Estou realmente tentando te ajudar. :) Cada uma destas questões pode gerar uma pergunta sua aqui no site, mas vc precisa ser objetivo(a).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu faço sempre uma coisa vejo código tento perceber se não perceber pergunto

Comment: Ótimo. Tem que perguntar mesmo. Só que é justamente aí que está o problema: a sua pergunta, do jeito que está, não está clara porque eu não consigo saber exatamente onde é a sua dificuldade (até porque parece que a sua dificuldade é: "não sei fazer nada" - e se for esse o caso, talvez seja melhor você realmente contratar alguém pra fazer no seu lugar). Entende? E como eu disse anteriormente, este site não é um fórum ou um classificado. Sério mesmo, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Vai ser útil. :)

Comment: Sugestão: clique em [edit] e coloque na pergunta o trecho de código em que você já obtém e (talvez) imprima os nomes das listas que usa. Dai fica mais fácil te ajudar, propondo uma solução de como sortear e juntar os nomes.

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu estou aqui para aprender eu faço o seguinte começo a fazer um programa, se não conseguir fazer alguma coisa pesquiso no google e no youtube se não consigo venho a este site e pergunto se ponho código é porque sei um pouco ou penso que está certo naquela parte, se não ponho é porque estou a tentar aprender e não encontro nenhuma suloção que me possa ajudar.

Comment: Melhorou com a edição. Retirei meu voto para fechar. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira vou editar outravez ja voltei a alterar o codigo

Answer (score 3):

Pekita, primeiro ponto `.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid())` é uma tecnica interresante quando queremos fazer um randomize no array, como na extensão abaixo.:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Porém você não precisa "embaralhar" todo o `Array` para pode pegar um elemento de forma aleatoria... imagina se a sua coleção tivesse 5.000 registros.

Outro ponto, já existe varias blibiotecas para montar strings aleatorias, uma delas é o [`Faker.Net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Faker.Net/), ela está disponivel para download no `Nuget` e o `Source` está disponivel no [`GitHub`](https://github.com/jonwingfield/Faker.Net).

Então apartir de agora, aconselho que começe a procurar pacotes pelo `NuGet` e estudar os seus respectivos codigos fonte (a maioria é disponibilizada no `NuGet` ou `SourceForge`)

Agora quando a obter uma combinação aleatoria de strings.:

```
var random = new Random();
var nomes = new[] { "Aaliyah", "Aaron", "Abagail", "Abbey", "Abbie", "Abbigail", "Abby", "Abdiel" };
var sobrenomes = new[] { "Abbott", "Abernathy", "Abshire", "Adams", "Altenwerth", "Anderson", "Ankunding", "Armstrong", "Auer", "Aufderhar" };
return nomes[random.Next(nomes.length)] + " " + sobrenomes[random.Next(sobrenomes.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Descubri a resposta lembrei-me de um código que eu usava no switch `break;` então fiz o mesmo no forever. Mas se voces souberem alguma maneira mais simples de fazer o código agradeceria que me dissesem

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var words = new[] { "apple", "mango", "papaya", "banana", "guava", "pineapple" };
    var wordsInRandomOrder = words.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = word;
        break;
    }

    foreach (var word in wordsInRandomOrder)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + word;
        break;
    }
```